# Sort DatagridColumn in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex3

I have a DatagridColumn in flex
with two names, TYPE and NAME

Now, when I am sorting a datagridcolumn, TYPE, it sorts the type using sortcomparefunction
and gives the result which contains grouped and sorted order of elements.
ex. if I sort for type I get elements in pdf, doc,ppt in grouped order, 
but they are internally not sorted, ex: for the pdf part, I have elements such as:
TYPE NAME
pdf  A1.pdf
pdf  X2.pdf
pdf  B1.pdf

here the filetypes are sorted , but for a particular filetype, the elements are not , please notice that B1 occurs after X2, which should be sorted

Is there a way I can sort the second datagridcolumn after sorting the first one according to filetype extensions?

I am using sortcomparefunction for sorting the elements according to type , which works fine.
the signature is:

private function sortTheTypeColumn(itemA:Object, itemB:Object):int

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
    protected function sortTheTypeColumn(x:Object, y:Object):int
    {
        var xType:String = String(x["TYPE"]).toLocaleLowerCase();
        var yType:String = String(y["TYPE"]).toLocaleLowerCase();

        var result:int = sortInternalCompare(xType, yType);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            var aName:String = String(x["NAME"]).toLocaleLowerCase();
            var bName:String = String(y["NAME"]).toLocaleLowerCase();

            result = sortInternalCompare(aName, bName);
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected function sortInternalCompare(x:String, y:String):int
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return 0;
        if (x == null)
            return 1;
        if (y == null)
            return -1;

        var result:int = x.localeCompare(y);

        if (result < -1)
            result = -1;
        if (result > 1)
            result = 1;

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: @Jason..Thank you very much for your guidance.